# Eclipse debug into java source, doesn't list member variables of the source classes

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm trying to debug into the JDK source files. To be more specific, I'm interested in studying the internal implementation of the Collection classes.

So I have created a Simple Java Project, added some sample code like this one:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HashMapWorking {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> demoMap = new HashMap<>();

        demoMap.put("one", "first");
        demoMap.put("two", "second");
        demoMap.put("three", "third");
    }
}
```

I need to know, for example, what happens when I call the `demoMap.put()` method.

I have added the source archive using the **Edit Source Lookup Path** dialog:

[image]

Now my problem is that when I debug into the `put()` method in the `java.util.HashMap` class, the **Variables** tab doesn't list out its member variables. Instead I just get to see the arguments being passed to the respective methods:

[image]

The local variables withing methods aren't captured either

What can I do to be able to debug through the java source the way I could debug into any other source classes?

I tried referencing the **src.zip** as well as the extracted version of src.zip in the **Edit Source Lookup Path** dialog, neither of them worked.

Kindly advise.

Comment: You have to step into to see those variables. In _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JRE_ you have probably a JRE instead of a JDK causing the troubles with the missing sources.

Comment: @howlger: a JRE doesn't contain src.zip, and the Oracle JREs at least don't use the directory name format shown.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Sure, because the JRE instead of a JDK in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ the sources have been missed. You run the application on a JRE with attached sources of a JDK, not on a JDK as you can see from the parameter name `arg0` instead of `key`. Independent of that, you have to [_Step Into_](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-stepinto.htm) to see what you want.

Comment: @howlger: I did try switching the _Installed JRE_ value among jdk and jre. In either case I didn't get it through.

Comment: @VikramSherigar With a JDK instead of a JRE you see the sources without the need to attach it and in the _Variables_ view `key` instead of `arg0` will be shown. To see the _local variables within the method"_ you have to [_Step Into_](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-stepinto.htm) as it has been stopped before the line in which the variable was first used. The _member variables_ (fields) of the class are not shown for static methods because static stuff has no reference to an instance.

Comment: @howlger: yes if using JRE you would not have source, but OP _did_ have source from the start and _was_ using JDK. Yes `hash(Object)` is static and doesn't display class fields, as both you and I said. No, local vars (and param names) _aren't_ displayed for Oracle JDK 8 builds, because those are compiled without the needed debuginfo; please try it.

Answer (score 1):

**Class fields.** In the display you posted, you are not actually stopped in the `HashMap.put(K,V)` method but in the `HashMap.hash(Object)` method (which `put` calls).  `hash(Object)` is a `static` method -- it executes without any 'instance' context (specifically, `this`).

If you go down the stack to the `put(K,V)` method (or any other instance method), you will see it has a HashMap object as `this`. If not already expanded, click the plus box to see all fields in the class.

Although static fields (only) are accessible to a static method (and depending on visibility, to methods in other classes that don't have or use an instance), the 'Variables' window/view doesn't have a way to find them. You can access *invididual* static fields in the 'Expressions' window/view -- although in standard (JDK) classes I have looked at static fields are mostly constants whose value is given in the source code, thus looking at them with the debugger isn't very useful.

**Local variables.** The older Oracle builds apparently are compiled *with* LineNumber (and SourceFile) debug information but *without* LocalVariable debug information. These are separate sub-options; see the help message or manual for `javac`. Without this information in the classfile, the debugger does not display local variables, or *names* for parameters (it does display *values* for parameters, as `arg0 arg1` etc, because *type* information is in the basic classfile data).

I don't know why they did this; perhaps it was a leftover from the pre-opened-source days.  The Oracle builds for newer versions (j9 and up) and *some* of the OpenJDK builds I could easily check *do* have LocalVariables. You could try one of those (using a newer version may depend to some extent on your Eclipse version).